# Authorised agent for joint authors in publication agreement

Tags: publications, authorship, copyright, publishers

For the publication of a paper each of the joint authors needs to sign a publication agreement with the publisher. Instead, only one author can sign as an 'authorised agent for joint authors'. Ignoring the specifics of this particular publisher, how does an author become an authorised agent generally in this respect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not nearly as complicated and formal as it sounds.  Usually what it means in practice is you email a copy of the agreement to the other authors and ask if it's okay with them.  If they all say yes, then that is your authorization to sign on their behalf.

As Fred says, the publisher doesn't usually require you to prove that you have the authorization of the other authors; but if you sign without their authorization, you could in principle be sued later.

Answer (score 2):

They're taking the word of the person who signs, that they're allowed to speak for everyone.

Or, in some contexts, the person is authorized by their own institution. For instance, a VP of a company signing for all employees who were authors,